# Metadata for Federated Authentication using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metadata, federation

I have a server which does the federated authentication.
I have metadata for Federation environment and the signing certificate.
I will have to access this server from my ruby on rails application server.
As per my understanding I have to provide federation metadata so that a connection can be set up from my application server to the federation server.
I am new to federation authentication.
Any suggestions on how to proceed  will be really helpful.

Regards,
Srikanth

Comment: Try here: https://craig.io/using-microsoft-adfs-with-ruby-on-rails-and-omniauth/